# Sphinx not working - Status active (exited)

Tags: sphinx

Sphinx installed and it was working. Suddenly it stopped and following error appearing

```
Sphinx error: connection to unix:///path/runtime/sphinx/var/sphinx.socket failed (errno=111, msg=Connection refused)
```

> ● sphinxsearch.service - LSB: Fast standalone full-text SQL search
>   engine    Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch)    Active: active
>   (exited) since Wed 2019-05-08 17:24:31 EDT; 3s ago   Process: 2039
>   ExecStop=/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>   Process: 2052 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch start (code=exited,
>   status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> May 08 17:24:31 bureaubureau systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Fast standalone
>   full-text SQL search engine... May 08 17:24:31 bureaubureau
>   systemd[1]: Started LSB: Fast standalone full-text SQL search engine.

Comment: What's in the searchd log?

Comment: searchd was not even working. I have fixed it by reinstalling sphinxsearch and it started working